# Compiling and running UNIX based code on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, unix, compilation, executable

Is there anyway to execute/run unix/linux executable on a mac (10.6)? Specifically, i'm trying to run this:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/CATS/

I have Xcode SDK/gcc/g++, but the source provided on this website is not compiling/executing on my mac (os x 10.6). That's where i need help.

Thanking in anticipation.

**Edit:**
"make -j16" produces following results:
[image: Console Output - 1]
[image: Console Output - 2]

Comment: The source is provided on the link you provided you will need to compile it for your mac platform.

Comment: How are you trying to compile it? Are you getting an error when you try to compile?

Comment: It is most definitely possible as highlighted by my answer. Could you please update the question with the specifics of the problem you have encountered?

Comment: question updated, with "make" result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just compiled this on my Mac.

```
wget http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/CATS/CATS20source.tgz
tar zxvf CATS20source.tgz
```

In `lp_solve_4.0/lpglob.h` I had to change the declaration of `extern size_t     yyleng;` (was `int`).

```
make -j16
```

And then...

```
 ./cats -help | head
CATS v2.1 (http://robotics.stanford.edu/CATS)
Kevin Leyton-Brown, Mark Pearson, Galen Andrew, Yoav Shoham; Stanford University
=================================================================================

What follows are the general parameters for CATS.
To see parameters for a specific distribution, select a distribution with -help

Required Parameters (no default values):
  -d [no default]: selects a distribution.  Valid options (without quotes) are:
     "arbitrary"; "arbitrary-npv"; "arbitrary-upv"; "matching"; "paths"; "regions";
```

### Update

This was with GCC v4.0.1.

To build with GCC v4.2.1, I had to add:

```
 #include <assert.h>
```

... to `Legacy.cpp`, `Param.cpp` and `featureCalc.cpp`, to fix compilation errors.

There are also a load of warnings that should be fixed and a patch sent to the maintainer.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this. Thanks. I'll see what i can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just download the source tar/zip and run `make` in the source directory. This assumes you have a C++ compiler and make installed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course : Mac OS X is an Unix system. You need to install [XCode SDK](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) that contains (in many other things) GCC 4.2 and make. After that, if you need a more complete Unix environment, you can look at [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: I have Xcode SDK/gcc/g++, but the source provided on this website is not compiling/executing on my mac (os x 10.6). That's where i need help.